# I am not able to get the return value on using json object

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to capture the json object using ajax post method, but I'm not able to get it.

My Jquery:

```
$.post($('#formsignin').attr('action'),
$('#formsignin').serialize(),
function(data, status){
    $("user_name").text(data.NameOfUser||'No value');
    $("user_name").text(data.EmailAddress||'No value');
},"json");
```

and my php:

```
$status1['NameOfUser'] = 'xxx';
$status1['EmailAddress'] = 'xxx@xyz.com';
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($status1);
exit(0);
```

Please tell me is there any other way to do this same functionality?

Comment: `user_name` seems like its an ID so your jquery handler should be `$('#user_name')`

Comment: also are you using `submit()` to submit your form? how are you calling the `$.post`?

Comment: $('#login').click(function (){                                                                            }); like this I am calling.

Comment: please include the HTML

Answer (score 0):

It seems fine, but be sure to surround you js code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //your js code
});
```